# OpenCV error zlib.h: no such file or directory

Tags: opencv

I am trying to follow this website to install opencv4 on Ubuntu 18.04.

https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-ubuntu-18-04/

But I get this error after `make`

```
In file included from /home/gosztolai/opencv/3rdparty/libpng/pngpriv.h:913:0,
                 from /home/gosztolai/opencv/3rdparty/libpng/png.c:14:
/home/gosztolai/opencv/3rdparty/libpng/pngstruct.h:30:10: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include "zlib.h"
```

I tried `sudo apt install zlib1g-dev` but the system says that it is already isntalled

Could someone help what is going on?

Comment: What is in cmake output?

Comment: It's too long to paste here to here's a link https://www.dropbox.com/s/47uv40aggrfrlwh/cmake_output?dl=0

Comment: One line says - Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY) (found suitable version "1.2.11", minimum required is "1.2.3")

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

libpng uses the zlib library for image compression. To install it in Ubuntu, run the following code in your bash terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

But because you already have it installed, and need a newer version, you need to update the library. Try to upgrade your packages, using this code:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade -y
```

Or you can try to remove it using apt and install again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe trying to recompile OpenCV using diffenrt compiler. So first you should run :

```
cd /(yourpath)/OpenCV
```

and then enter the CMakeList.txt and find this code:

```
ocv_include_directories(${OPENCV_CONFIG_FILE_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

change it into:

```
ocv_include_directories(${OPENCV_CONFIG_FILE_INCLUDE_DIR})
ocv_include_directories(./3rdparty/zlib)
```

And then, you should rerun cmake, and then `make install`

If you still meet a problem called

```
error: size of array ‘_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_0’ is negative
```

you should do following steps:

```
sudo gedit /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h
```

find these codes:

```
typedef signed long gint64;
typedef unsigned long guint64;

#define G_GINT64_CONSTANT(val)  (val##L)
#define G_GUINT64_CONSTANT(val) (val##UL)
#define G_GINT64_MODIFIER "l"
#define G_GINT64_FORMAT "li"
#define G_GUINT64_FORMAT "lu"

#define GLIB_SIZEOF_VOID_P 8
#define GLIB_SIZEOF_LONG   8
#define GLIB_SIZEOF_SIZE_T 8
#define GLIB_SIZEOF_SSIZE_T 8
```

change them into:

```
typedef signed long long gint64;
typedef unsigned long long guint64;

#define G_GINT64_CONSTANT(val)  (val##L)
#define G_GUINT64_CONSTANT(val) (val##UL)
#define G_GINT64_MODIFIER "l"
#define G_GINT64_FORMAT "li"
#define G_GUINT64_FORMAT "lu"

#define GLIB_SIZEOF_VOID_P 8
#define GLIB_SIZEOF_LONG   8
#define GLIB_SIZEOF_SIZE_T 4
#define GLIB_SIZEOF_SSIZE_T 4
```

rerun `make install`

**Good Luck!**